# How should I go about optimizing a hash table for a given population?

Tags: java

Say I have a population of key-value pairs which I plan to store in a hash table.  The population is fixed and will never change.  What optimizations are available to me to make the hash table as fast as possible?  Which optimizations should I concentrate on?  This is assuming I have a lot of space.  There will be a reasonable number of pairs (say no more than 100,000).

**EDIT:** I want to optimize look up.  I don't care how long it takes to build.

Comment: Posting this as a comment because it doesnt really answer your question.  But if you are using a java.util.Hashtable, dont.  Use a java.util.HashMap instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make sure that your key's hash to unique values.  This will ensure that every lookup will be constant time, and thus, as fast as possible.

Since you can never have more than 100,000 keys, it is entirely possible to have 100,000 hash values.

Also, make sure that you use the constructor that takes an `int` to specify the initial capacity (Set it to 100,000), and a float to set the load factor. (Use `1`)  Also, doing this requires that you have a perfect hash function for your keys.  But, this will result in the fastest possible lookup, in the least amount of memory.

Comment: *I would make sure that your key's hash to unique values.*  Well, that's easier to say than do for 100000 keys.

Comment: 100k keys is not that big. You're not going to get many, if any, collisions. If you do happen to get a couple, don't worry: lookup is still generally going to be very fast. Worry when you can actually show that collisions are causing overall performance issues. For 100k items, that's very unlikely.

Oh, and do NOT set your initial capacity to your expected size. As soon as you exceed your load factor (defaults to 75% of capacity), your storage is likely to double. That would cause more issues.

Comment: @Gary, oops, I forgot to tell him to set the load factor to 1.  That makes the most sense right?

Comment: @Justin Broadly speaking, yes, but there is something of a trade-off between memory and performance. Having exactly 100k buckets for exactly 100k keys requires a perfectly even hash, which is unlikely. Allowing for more buckets allows an increase in the hashing space. A load factor of 0.75 is the default because it's often optimal but YMMV.

Comment: @Gary, well, if you are trying to optimize something perfectly, then you probably want a perfect hash.

Comment: @Justin absolutely, but coming up with a perfectly even hash algorithm for an arbitrary keyspace is extremely difficult and not worth the time. Unless it's obvious (unique integer keys, for example), go with a general alg and trade-off some space in your hash table for lookup speed.

Comment: @Gary, I agree that it's a waste of time, and I'd never do it.  But, you could...if you wanted to...100,000 case switch?

Comment: @Justin I'd be sceptical of the performance of such a switch. In Java (pre-7), you can't use switch statements with anything but certain numeric types and enums (already unique) so using it would get you nothing. Post-7 or in another language, the switch would be finding the right branch to jump to based on the case value (your key, in this case). To do that, it's going to hash it with a general purpose algorithm, so you end up doing more work to get the same result.

Comment: @Gary, I'm not arguing that it *should* be done, just that it *could.*

Comment: @Gary, all of this thinking is giving me a headache..I'm gonna get back to work creating Win Forms in Visual studio, dragging and dropping components wherever I want.

Comment: @jjnguy, just fell upon this. Notes: the explanation about hashtable is probably incorrect. It's somewhat correct for java.util.Hashtable but entirely not for java.util.HashMap. If you use 1F factor, you'd be better off w/ a simple Object[] since "pefect" hash function is free to be mangled (bit twiddled, and *it is*) to ensure better bit spread in the lower bits (i.e. turning into not pefect). Overall advising on 1F load factor is going to cause more harm. Also, java.util.HashMap capacity does not factor in the load factor and it's always power of 2 (to skip the expensive mod operation)

Comment: @bestsss, Thanks for the extra info.  I didn't know that the hashmmap mangles my bits.  I wish I knew as much as I thought I did.

Comment: @jjnguy, that's a nice statement, I found out I ain't that good when I saw (~1996) that Delphi was generating better assembler than my own hand-written. Yet, nowadays I still take time (and interest) to study the impl. of virtually all java classes (incl sum.misc). As hash maps go: they defend vs poorly written hash functions, so the spread is virtually never `Object.hashCode()%capacity`.(java.util.Hashtable does it exactly like that w/ 0x7fffffff mask to ensure no negative hashes)

Comment: @bestss, I bet I would learn a lot if I looked into some of the common classes I use every day.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to optimize a hash table, you want to minimize collisions in the determination of your hash, so your buckets won't contain more than one item and the hash-search will return immediately.

Most of the time, that means that you should measure the output of your hash function on the problem space. So i guess i'd recommend looking into that

Answer (score 1):

Ensure there are no collisions. If there are no collisions, you are guaranteed O(1) constant look-up time. The next optimization would then be the look-up.

Use a profiler to optimize piece by piece. It's hard to without that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to make a large hash table such that there are no collisions at all, it will be ideal. Since your insertions and lookups will done in constant time.

But if that is not possible, try to choose a hash function such that your keys get distributed uniformly across the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

[Perfect hashing algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) deal with the problem, but may not scale to 100k objects. I found a [Java MPH package](http://sux4j.dsi.unimi.it/), but haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

If the population is known at compile time, then the optimal solution is to use a minimal perfect hash function (MPH). The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) on this subject links to several Java tools that can generate these.

Answer (score 0):

The optimization must be done int the `hashCode` method of the key `class`. The thing to have in mind is to implement this method to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the perfect hashing algorithm to give totally unique values to 100K objects is likely to be close to impossible. Consider the birthday paradox. The date on which people are born can be considered a perfect hashing algorithm yet if you have more than 23 people you are more than likely to have a collision, and that is in a table of 365 dates.

So how big a table will you need to have no collisions in 100K?

If your keys are strings, your optimal strategy is a tree, not binary but n-branch at each character. If the keys are lower-case only it is easier still as you need just 26 whenever you create a branch.

We start with 26 keys. Follow the first character, say f
f might have a value associated with it. And it may have sub-trees. Look up a subtree of o. This leads to more subtrees then look up the next o. (You knew where that was leading!). If this doesn't have a value associated with it, or we hit a null sub-tree on the way, we know the value is not found.

You can optimise the space on the tree where you hit a point of uniqueness. Say you have a key january and it becomes unique at the 4th character. At this point where you assign the value you also store the actual string associated with it. In our example there may be one value associated with foo but the key it relates to may be food, not foo.

I think google search engines use a technique similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

The key question is what your key is. (No pun intended.) As others have pointed out, the goal is to minimize the number of hash collisions. If you can get the number of hash collisions to zero, i.e. your hash function generates a unique value for every key that is actually passed to it, you will have a perfect hash.

Note that in Java, a hash function really has two steps: First the key is run through the hashCode function for it's class. Then we calculate an index value into the hash table by taking this value modulo the size of the hash table.

I think that people discussing the perfect hash function tend to forget that second step. Even if you wrote a hashCode function that generated a unique value for every key passed to it, you could still get an absolutely terrible hash if this value modulo the hash table size is not unique. For example, say you have 100 keys and your hashCode function returns the values 1, 1001, 2001, 3001, 4001, 5001, ... 99001. If your hash table has 100,000 slots, this would be a perfect hash. Every key gets its own slot. But if it has 1000 slots, they all hash to the same slot. It would be the worst possible hash.

So consider constructing a good hash function. Take the extreme cases. Suppose that your key is a date. You know that the dates will all be in January of the same year. Then using the day of the month as the hash value should be as good as it's going to get: everything will hash to a unique integer in a small range. On the other hand, if your dates were all the first of the month for many years and many months, taking the day of the month would be a terrible hash, as every actual key would map to "1".

My point being that if you really want to optimize your hash, you need to know the nature of your data. What is the actual range of values that you will get?